# Why is David able to continue being with his wives after they are captured

Tags: king-david, samuel-shmuel-book-of

In 1 Shmuel 30 we learn that David's wives were taken captive by Amalekites. David and his men were able to retrieve them sometime later, however enough time seems to have passed that the captors could have raped those women in the intervening time. My understanding (can't recall the source) is that if the wives of the king are raped they are no longer permitted to the king. Yet we know that David had children from these wives.

Therefore I would like to know why David was allowed to continue to be with his wives after they were captured

Comment: There is a debate in the Yerushalmi as to whether the rule you present regarding a king's wives is true. https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Sanhedrin.2.3.5?lang=bi

Comment: Why do you assume that they were raped?

Comment: Maybe they testified for each other that they weren’t - see Kesubos 23b

Comment: The king may have not been with them just put them away